# Closing mongoose connection and multiple connections showing up

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I'm using mongoose to maintain a connection with the database for my node.js app.

What I am doing is essentially open a connection the the database when the app starts and close the connection when it terminates. It's working fine and I have absolutely no issues querying and manipulating data, so no issues there.

I have a fair idea about how it works and how connections are pooled. However, I noticed that when the app is running, I randomly get an extra connection to my database - [Multiple connections to DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czhHO.png)

I'm using nodemon to track any file changes in my project but since the app closes every time nodemon cause it to restart, the connection should be destroyed because the app is closing, right? 

Is it advised to close connections anywhere while the app is up and running and open it again as and when required? I haven't done that anywhere because from what I've read, it takes more time to open and close connections for every query. Could this be because I'm not disconnecting anywhere except for when the app closes?